# Dropzone node.js upload image to the server via JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch, react-dropzone

I am trying to upload an image to the server so that the image can be saved on the server. The server language used is PHP. The front end site is react.js and to choose the files I am using [react-dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone/). The image is selected and I handle the dropped image in this function.

```
 onImageDrop(image) {
    let addImage = this.state.images;
    addImage.unshift(image[0]);
    this.setState({images: addImage});
}
```

I then map the images the the screen in the render method. The images do go to the screen.

```
    {this.state.images.map((f, i) =>
    <img key={i} src={f.preview} alt={f.name} style={{
            border: "2px dashed gray",
            margin: "10px",
            width: "200px",
            padding: "5px"
        }}/>
    )}
```

The Image is stored in a local URL that I can preview on the client. If i console log the file it looks like this.

> File {preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/9b499d57-9248-499c-8974-607143f2ed1d", name: "IMG_20140421_151555.jpg", lastModified: 1398090260000, lastModifiedDate: Mon Apr 21 2014 15:24:20 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}

What I want to do is sent the file as a blob in JSON format to a PHP script so that I can save the image on the server.
This is the fetch method to the server. I am just trying to send one image at the minute.

```
validateandSubmit(){
    fetch(serverScripts + "admin/Controllers/imageController.php", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            action: "ADD_IMAGE",
            name: this.state.images[0].name,
            blob: this.state.images[0].preview
        }),
        mode: 'cors'
    }).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });


}
```

and the PHP Script is

```
<?php

   $_postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

   if ($_postData['action'] == "ADD_IMAGE"){
    echo json_encode(['ImageClass' => 'image received', 'success' => true]);

    $theFile = fopen($_postData['name'], "w");
    $fileData = $_postData['blob'];
    fwrite($theFile, $fileData);
    fclose($theFile);

  }
```

The file that is written to the server is empty. How can I send the image?

I am a student and new to programming. If I am way off could you tell me any other ways that will work better.

If you need any further information please ask me. Thanks